# Kerberos: difference between UPN and SPN

Tags: kerberos, samba, gssapi, spn

I'm now kerberizing a cross-platform application with GSSAPI.
While I'm not clear about the difference between UPN and SPN.

The development environment is a Samba4 AD DC server on CentOS 6.4 with a Windows server 2008 R2 a member box in the domain, say EXAMPLE.COM (You may be curious why not use Win2008 as DC directly. And as I stated previously, the application is cross-platform, I'm now testing in this setting. The normal Win DC-Linux MEM setting works fine.).
I create a new user `foobar:users` to run the application.
When I use `foobar@EXAMPLE.COM`, i.e. the UPN, to authenticate the application against Kerberos, I keep receiving

> Kerberos: Principal may not act as server ERROR

Following a [thread](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2012-July/168331.html) on Samba maillist, I think I should create a service principal name say `app/dc.example.com` for the UPN with `samba-tool`

```
samba-tool spn add app/dc.example.com foobar
```

This time I will receive another error

> Samba4 KDC - no such entry found in hdb

My question is what's the difference between a UPN and SPN?
By `samba-tool spn list foobar`, it says `foobar` *has* servicePrincipalName `app/dc.example.com`.
How could I associate a UPN with an SPN?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put,

- **UPN:** An entity performing client requests to some service. Entity may be human or machine. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_user_principal_name_gly).
- **SPN:** An entity processing requests for a specific service, e.g., HTTP, LDAP, SSH, etc. Machine only. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_service_principal_name_gly).

A UPN retrieves a *service ticket* for an SPN to use that actual service.

If your `samba-tool` call your request samba to register the SPN `app/dc.example.com` to the UPN `foobar`. Since You have not provided the realm of the SPN and UPN, Samba will assume the default realm of the machine this call is performed from. In Windows terms, you mostly bind an SPN to a machine UPN. Which is always: `<name>$@<REALM>`. Note the dollar sign.