# Kerberos: Windows Server 2008 and Linux KDC Interoperation

Tags: linux, windows-authentication, windows-server-2008-r2, samba, kdc

Still a Kerberos related problem as a subsequent of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234192/kerberos-difference-between-upn-and-spn).
In fact, I just want to enable the Windows Server 2008 and Linux KDC interoperability, so a full featured Samba server is not necessary.

After another day's trial, I find this step-by-step guide on [Microsoft website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742433.aspx#EDAA).
In my case, I just need a Linux KDC and a standalone Windows server.
I followed the instructions step-by-step, however, when I finally try to login the system as a Kerberos REALM user, I receive error saying that it cannot establish trust between domain controller and the box.

It's my first time enter into the interoperation field, any configuration steps that I missed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want the KDC to be authoritative, the 2k8 DC, or both?  FWIW the guide you link is for joining a Win2K workstation to a KRB5 KDC.

Comment: @jtravaglini Thanks for your concern. I want to join a KRB5 KDC exactly as the link is, while the only difference is my Windows server is 2k8, though I thought that may not be a very big problem.